# Question Regarding Logarithm

Tags: logarithms

Sir
I have an Equation $X^9 - X^3 = 24$.
I solved it using Algebra, and the answer is $X = 1.44$ OR $\sqrt[3]{3}$.
This is an Exponential Equation.
Can this Equation be Solved using Logarithm ?
If yes, then can you show me the steps, Hint, Clue ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "exponential equation"? Because those are solutions, not exponential equations.

Comment: $X^9-X^3=24$ is a polynomial of degree $9$, and specifically there is some polynomial $g$ of degree $3$ such that $X^9-X^3=24$ if and only if $g(X^3)=0$. Therefore the equation can be solved with Cardano's formula. The equation isn't "exponential" by any reasonable definition.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, when $~a,b \in \Bbb{R^+},~$ there is no simple way of expressing $~\ln(a - b)~$ in terms of $~\ln(a)~$ and $~\ln(b).$